# I've already customized my own YouTube channel url - Why can't I use the Subscribe Button widget?

Tags: youtube

This is the [script](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button) for the YouTube Subscribe Button:

```
<script src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js'></script>
<div class='g-ytsubscribe' data-channel='EcooperaTrento'>
```

and this is my channel:

```
https://www.youtube.com/c/EcooperaTrento
```

why it can't render the button? It says error.
It has been always worked for any other Channels I have.

EDIT: using `data-channelid` works, but it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Please show what kind of error it's showing.

Comment: Just it says "ERROR" on the plugin. Open a jsfiddle and copy and paste the code.